# Extracting a series of patches from an image in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, tensorflow

I’m trying to extract a series of 255x255 pixel images / patches from an image in Google Earth Engine. (These patches are going to be used as inputs into a model in Tensorflow — [here](https://github.com/chrisyeh96/africa_poverty_clean), if you are curious). The first patch should be centred at a location and subsequent patches forming a grid emanating out from the original patch for two cells in each direction.

I have a function which extracts these patches which I’ve adapted from the author’s function, but I want to modify it to take additional patches in the neighbourhood of that centre patch as illustrated below.

My question is how should I go about extracting those additional patches from the neighbourhood of the original patch?

- If I were to create a set of points displaced by 255px * 30m/px = 7650m to represent the centroid of these cells and map the function across these points, would I need to worry about any small deviations in the spatial resolution from 30m/px leading to overlapping samples?
- I imagine the most direct way to solve this would involve converting the image into an array and sampling from this array, but I am not sure how I might go about doing that and haven’t been able to figure this out from Google’s documentation.
- Alternatively, am I better to just export a single larger patch that is (255x5) x (255x5) pixels in dimension, and dividing this larger image into 255x255 px patches locally using Tensorflow?

To give a simple example of where I’m stuck: this is where I am now.

```
import ee


ee.Initialize()


# Function to extract image patch from image
def sample_patch(point: ee.Feature, patches_array: ee.Image,
                 scale: float) -> ee.Feature:
    """
    Extracts an image patch at a specific point.

    Args
    - point: ee.Feature
    - patches_array: ee.Image, Array Image
    - scale: int or float, scale in meters of the projection to sample in

    Returns: ee.Feature, 1 property per band from the input image
    """
    arrays_samples = patches_array.sample(
        region=point.geometry(),
        scale=scale,
        projection='EPSG:3857',
        factor=None,
        numPixels=None,
        dropNulls=False,
        tileScale=12)
    return arrays_samples.first().copyProperties(point)


# PARAMS
start="2020-01-01"
end="2020-12-31"
lat=51.7520
lon=1.2577
scale=30

bucket="jordanimahori-public"
file_name="test_sample"

# Create Feature Collection of Locations
pt=ee.Geometry.Point(lon, lat)
points=ee.FeatureCollection(pt)

# 
max_extent = pt.buffer(distance=7650*(3.5)).bounds()        # 30m/px*255pxs*3rings
sample_region = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR").filterDate(start, end).filterBounds(max_extent).first()

kern = ee.Kernel.square(radius=127, units='pixels')
patches_array = sample_region.neighborhoodToArray(kern)

# ***Function I want to expand to also create patches in the neighbourhood of each pt***
samples = points.map(lambda pt: sample_patch(pt, patches_array, scale))

# Export
task = ee.batch.Export.table.toCloudStorage(
            collection=samples,
            description=file_name,
            bucket=bucket,
            fileNamePrefix=file_name,
            fileFormat='TFRecord')

task.start()
```

[image]